# Pipe symbol not converted through TeX4ht

Tags: symbols, punctuation, tex4ht

My codes are follow:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

This is for test | Test

\end{document}
```

If I convert this through `TeX4ht` then the pipe symbol `|` converted as emdash, how can I fix this? Please advise...

Comment: you also get a dash if you use pdflatex so the html conversion by tex4ht is correct here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I use the package `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, then the conversion issue was fixed...Thanks to `David`...